# При 3х мерном построении используются матрицы Model -> View -> Perspective. Зачем мат. Frustum?

Tags: 3d, graphics, матрицы

Цель:
Пишу Software renderer упрощённый для своей граф. библиотеки, сейчас непосредственно тружусь над классом матриц 4х4.

Проблема:
При штудировании примеров на GitHub увидел, что часто в классе матриц есть реализация как основных методов (SetViewMat, SetPerspMat, Transl, Rot, Scale, и.т.д ), так и (LookAt и Frustum).
C LookAt понятно, альтернатива матрице вида.
А вот с Frustum не понимаю для чего. По реализации она схожа с Perspective.

Если правильно понимаю, то логика построения такая:
Объект(VertArray) -> TransformMat -> ViewMat(или LookAt) -> Perspective -> Растеризатор.

Вопрос:
Какое место и значение в этой цепи занимает матрица преобразования Frustum?

Просьба:
Прошу написать цепочку преобразований (пусть в упрощённом виде, как пример выше).

Comment: Дайте ссылки на непонятные примеры, так будет проще объяснять.

Математическую часть классного курса https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer кодировал я (там шаблончики на C++).

Comment: @gbg Да, эта ссылка уже давно в закладках. Отличный материал! По поводу темы вопроса.  
  
Ссылка: Методы setFrustum, View и Perspective  
(https://github.com/kittyous/OpenGL/blob/7937533abb290ed76becf677fe8c67f1ccb75f6b/OpenGl/src/math/Mat4x4.h)  
  
Ссылка 2:  Методы SetPerspectiveProjectionMatrix, SetPixelRatioMatrix, SetScreenSpaceMatrix  
(https://github.com/Victormeriqui/Console3D/blob/master/Console3D/Console3D/Matrix.hpp)  
  
Интересен именно пусть и упрощённый но некий типовой порядок работы с матрицами и на каком этапе включается Frustum (Для отсечения? но в какой момент?)